# Finding the expectation of the product of four normally distributed random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ are four normally distributed random variables that may be dependent, each with zero mean. Suppose further that

$X_1 \sim N(0,\sigma_1^2)$, $X_2 \sim N(0,\sigma_2^2)$, $X_3 \sim N(0,\sigma_3^2)$, $X_4 \sim N(0,\sigma_4^2)$

I would like to find:

$$
E(X_1X_2X_3X_4)
$$

Some options come to mind. One is to use the Kurtosis of normal distribution. However, this is limited as I only know $E(X_1^4)$ for ONE random variable. The second that comes to mind is to use characteristic or moment generating functions and start taking lots of derivatives. The final way is to directly attack it using four integrals on the joint pdf. I was wondering if there was an easy way to calculate this. Thanks!

Comment: You would always need their joint distribution. For the trivial case in which they are jointly independent it's equal to zero.

Comment: Use [Isserlis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  Consider:

Case 1:
$X_1 \sim\mathcal N(0,1), X_1=X_2= X_3=X_4$ then $\mathsf E(X_1 X_2 X_3 X_4) = \mathsf E(X_1^4)=3$

Case 2: $X_1 \sim\mathcal N(0,1), X_1=X_2= X_3=-X_4$ then $\mathsf E(X_1 X_2 X_3 X_4) = \mathsf E(-X_1^4)=-3$

Case 3: $X_1 \sim\mathcal N(0,1), X_3\sim\mathcal N(0,1), X_1=X_2, X_3=X_4, X_1 \perp X_3$ then $\mathsf E(X_1 X_2 X_3 X_4) = 0$

In conclusion: We can make no claim about the expectation of the product without knowing the dependency of the random variables.